# Either type implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, either

In all the libraries implementing `Either` in JavaScript, I notice that `Either.of` returns a `Right`, I feel that I'm missing something about why that is, does anyone know? Also my intuition for an `Either` implementation is something like `new Either(true, 'foo')` for a `right` and `new Either(false, 'err')` for a `left` and maybe have static methods like `Either.right` and `Either.left` but all the libraries seem to have a base class `Either` and sub classes `Left` and `Right`, I also feel that I'm missing something about why most of them decided to implement it with inheritance?

Comment: What about composition? `Either(false, 'err') || Either(true, 'foo')`

Comment: You can think of `of` as a computation that has the potential for an effect. What is `Either`'s effect? Unwind the stack and yield an error message (please note that `Either` can also be used more generally). If `of` yields a `Left` each invocation would actually perform the effect. This would be far less useful. We only want the potential for the effect, which means `of` is hypothetically capable of throwing an error, because it is of type `Either`, but in reality it never does.

Comment: Is it correct to think about `of` as a way to get the computation going, I mean from something that is definitively a `Right`

Answer (score 4):

Either is a simple prototypical Sum Type. It's like a IF-ELSE-THEN Constructor (EITHER-LEFT-RIGHT).

So, the construct `either` recieve either a Left or Right with value.
Here is the functional approache of Left, Right and Either in pure Javascript.

```
const Left   = x => f => g => f (x);
const Right  = x => f => g => g (x);
const either = e => f => g => e (f) (g);

// example:
either( Left(0)  )(x => x + 1)(x => x-1) //  1
either( Right(0) )(x => x + 1)(x => x-1) // -1
```

*Sidenote*:
You do not need the function `either`, because if you would apply Beta-Reduction you will see that `either === identity`. It is just syntactic sugar.

I give you a better example and build a function that check if the argument is a Integer value or not and return it as *either*:

```
const eitherJsNumOrOther = val =>
    Number.isInteger(val)
        ? Right(val)
        : Left(`${val}, is not a integer`);

// either function        left-case      right-case   
eitherJsNumOrOther( 10  )(console.error)(x => x + 5) // 15
eitherJsNumOrOther("bla")(console.error)(x => x + 5) // prints to console: bla, is not a integer
```

Hope that gives you a better understanding about *either* in the FP.

By the way. With *either* you can easy build the Maybe-Type.

```
const Nothing  = Left();
const Just     = Right ;
const maybe    = either;

// and can use the either construct for a maybe-Number-Function for example
const maybeNumber = val =>
    eitherJsNumOrOther(val)
    ( Nothing   )
    ( Just(val) )
```